# Each Row is a Break Object Evaluate Multiple Column Values Per Row/Break Object with User AND OR Operator Logic

Tags: vba, excel, object, collections

I have the following criteria which a user inputs onto an excel sheet. I am trying to code the user input in a way which passes these variables as parameters and sorts a raw data set.

```
 Field      Criteria I          Criteria II         Criteria III            Criteria IV
```

> ```
> MsgStr    Next    1008001 OR  Next    1002001 OR  Next 1003001 OR Next 1009001 AND    Next
> PriceDiff >   -25.01  AND <   25.01   AND Next                        
> AssetCUR  = AcctCUR   END
> ```

I have compiled the user input into a 2D Array which each Field `MsgStr`, Criteria `1008001`, Operator `And`, `OR`,`=`,`<`,`>`, among all the other Fields `Price Diff`

**All Fields are Column Headers** and the criteria for each field are the cells within each Column. At MOST each Column will only have one Field, i.e. Each Row will Either be `1008001` or `100xxxx`. Other Fields/Column Headers might have cells which I need to evaluate upon such an amount is equal `x` or greater than `>` `-25` **AND** less than `<` `25` but At most the `PriceDiff` Column **PER ROW** will only have one value. Further ALL criteria under each Column will only have one value. And the last criteria for this break is Column `AssetCur` must `=` or `<>` the Value/Currency for the **same row** under a different column in this user criteria, `AssetCUR` must `=` `AcctCur`.

- In other words I feel I could better explain as Each Row is an
  Accounting Break or short **A Break Object** So I have created a
  `Break Class` with all my Fields as class variables and now I need to
  evaluate the variables WITHIN each Row/Break Object according to the
  value (AT MAX) one value per each cell under each Column PER
  ROW/Break Object.

I have a 2D String Array for All My Break Categories. Position (1,1) is Break Category **SMALL Breaks** (1,1), and then the Criteria follows in all columns after the first Column in each 2D slot of the array. The Purpose of the 2D array is just so I can Loop Through The user input sheet and capture the data. This was the easier way I could capture the user logic.
`SMALL BREAKS` (1,2) `MsgStr1` (1,3)`Next`(1,4) `1008001  OR  Next    1002001 OR  Next    1003001  OR Next    1009001 AND Next    PriceDiff   >   -25.01  AND <   25.01   AND Next    AssetCUR    =   AcctCUR END`

And then for example another Break Category would be (3,1) **Cash Break**
`CASH`(3,1) `MsgStr`(3,2)`Next`(3,3)`1001000100  END`

Thereby each Break Category has the User Logic Associated with the **Break Category** I would like to return upon evaluating the data within the c
If a Row/Break Object is equal to ANY of these 4 `MsgStrings` AND the `PriceDiff` is within `>-$25` AND `<$25` AND has a `EUR` `AssetCUR` which also equal the `AcctCUR` which for this break is also `EUR` (But could be JPY or USD for example) I need to code the code to evaluate this.

```
    Sub Implement_Mapping()
Dim aMapRow As Integer, aMapCol As Integer
Dim tempStrBreak As String
Dim tempStrCrit As String
Dim CurrentBreakCat As String
Dim CurrentField As String
Dim andFLAG As Boolean

Dim ImplementBI As BreakInfo
Dim ImplementObjLSL As Collection
    Dim qQueue As New queue
    Dim aResult As Variant
    Dim index As Long
    Dim vValue As Variant
'''basic Queue
Dim queueAND As Object


Set ImplementObjLSL = New Collection

    For aMapRow = LBound(aLogic, 1) To UBound(aLogic, 1)
         For aMapCol = LBound(aLogic, 2) To UBound(aLogic, 2)

             If IsInArrayByVal(aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol), Break_List) = True Then
                CurrentBreakCat = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)
Set ImplementBI = New BreakInfo
                aMapCol = aMapCol + 1
            Else
                aMapCol = aMapCol + 1
            End If

greaterTHAN = False
lessTHAN = False
eqEQUALS = False
noEQUALS = False

                                If IsInArrayByVal(aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol), Field_List) = True Then
                                    CurrentField = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)
                                    aMapCol = aMapCol + 1
                                End If
                           If (aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol) <> "" And aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol) <> "Next") Then



                                    If IsInArrayByVal(aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol), Operator_List) = True Then
                                        Select Case aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)
                                            Case "<"
                                                lessTHAN = True
                                                aMapCol = aMapCol + 1
                                            Case ">"
                                                greaterTHAN = True
                                                aMapCol = aMapCol + 1
                                            Case "<>"
                                                noEQUALS = True
                                                aMapCol = aMapCol + 1
                                            Case "="
                                                eqEQUALS = True
                                                aMapCol = aMapCol + 1
                                        End Select


                                    ElseIf aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol) = "OR" Then

                                        Do While aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol) <> "AND"
                                            If (aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol) <> "Next" And aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol) <> "OR") Then
                                            Debug.Print aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                                qQueue.Enqueue aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)
                                            End If
                                            aMapCol = aMapCol + 1
                                            Debug.Print aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)
                                        Loop
                                        GoTo HereSkipII

                                    ElseIf aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol) = "AND" Then
                                        andFLAG = True
                                        GoTo HereSkip
                                    End If


                            Select Case CurrentField
                                Case "AcctCUR"
                                    ImplementBI.AcctCUR = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "AssetCur"
                                    ImplementBI.AssetCUR = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "AssetID"
                                    ImplementBI.AssetID = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "Coupon"
                                    ImplementBI.Coupon = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "EntityID"
                                    ImplementBI.EntityID = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "EntityName"
                                    ImplementBI.EntityName = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "InvType"
                                    ImplementBI.InvType = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "IssueDes"
                                    ImplementBI.IssueDes = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "IssueName"
                                    ImplementBI.IssueName = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "LedgAcctDes"
                                    ImplementBI.LedgAcctDes = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "LedgerAMT"
                                    ImplementBI.LedgerAMT = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "LngSht"
                                    ImplementBI.LngSht = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "MatDate"
                                    ImplementBI.MatDate = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "MsgStr"
                                    ImplementBI.MsgStr = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "NetAMTL"
                                    ImplementBI.NetAMTL = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "PAID"
                                    ImplementBI.PAID = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "PAIDType"
                                    ImplementBI.PAIDType = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "PriceDiff"


                                    If ImplementBI.PriceDiff = 0 Then 'If IsEmpty(ImplementBI.PriceDiff) = False Then
                                        ImplementBI.PriceDiff = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)
                                    ElseIf (ImplementBI.PriceDiff <> 0 And ImplementBI.PriceDiff2 = 0) Then
                                        ImplementBI.PriceDiff2 = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)
                                    ElseIf (ImplementBI.PriceDiff2 <> 0 And ImplementBI.PriceDiff2 <> 0) Then
                                        ImplementBI.PriceDiff3 = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)
                                            'Set queueAND = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")
                                            'queueAND.Enqueue aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)
                                    End If


                                Case "PST"
                                    ImplementBI.PST = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "RowNo"
                                    ImplementBI.RowNo = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "RuleID"
                                    ImplementBI.RuleID = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "Sector"
                                    ImplementBI.Sector = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "SecurityType"
                                    ImplementBI.SecurityType = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "ShareClass"
                                    ImplementBI.ShareClass = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "SrcDes"
                                    ImplementBI.SrcDes = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "SubSecType"
                                    ImplementBI.SubSecType = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "UpDate"
                                    ImplementBI.UpDate = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                Case "ValDate"
                                    ImplementBI.ValDate = aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)

                                End Select




HereSkip:
                 End If
                    aMapCol = aMapCol + 1
                    Debug.Print aLogic(aMapRow, aMapCol)
                 Loop
HereSkipII:


        Next aMapCol
    Next aMapRow

End Sub
```

Here is Where I Covert my Excel WorkSheet into all Objects:

```
Sub Fill_LSL_Objects()
Dim aMrow As Integer, aMcol As Integer

Dim BI As BreakInfo
Dim ObjLSL As Collection

Dim key As Long


    Set ObjLSL = New Collection

For aMrow = LBound(aMRecon, 1) To UBound(aMRecon, 1)
    For aMcol = LBound(aMRecon, 2) To UBound(aMRecon, 2)

                If aMcol = 2 And aMrow > 1 Then

                    Set BI = New BreakInfo

                    BI.EntityID = CStr(aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol))
                    BI.ShareClass = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 1)
                    BI.Sector = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 2)
                    BI.AssetID = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 3)
                    BI.AcctCUR = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 5)
                    BI.IssueName = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 6)
                    BI.PAID = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 7)
                    BI.AssetCUR = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 8)
                    BI.ValDate = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 9)
                    BI.LedgerAMT = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 10)
                    BI.NetAMTL = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 11)
                    BI.PriceDiff = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 14)
                    BI.RuleID = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 15)
                    BI.SrcDes = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 17)
                    BI.MsgStr = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 18)
                    BI.UpDate = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 20)
                    BI.LngSht = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 25)
                    BI.PAIDType = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 41)
                    BI.Coupon = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 42)
                    BI.MatDate = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 43)
                    BI.SecurityType = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 44)
                    BI.InvType = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 45)
                    BI.PST = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 46)
                    BI.IssueDes = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 48)
                    BI.SubSecType = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 58)
                    BI.EntityName = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 59)
                    BI.LedgAcctDes = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol + 62)
                    BI.RowNo = aMrow


                    key = key + 1
                    ObjLSL.Add BI, CStr(key)

                End If
        Next aMcol


    Next aMrow

    xrow = 0
    Dim Break As Object

        For Each Break In ObjLSL

           If (Break.MsgStr = 1008001 Or Break.MsgStr = 1002001 Or Break.MsgStr = 1003001 Or Break.MsgStr = 1009001) And _
            (Break.PriceDiff > -25.01 And Break.PriceDiff < 25.01) And _
            (StrComp(Break.AssetCUR, Break.AcctCUR, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then

                aTab(Break.RowNo, 1) = "SMALL BREAKS"
'                aTab(Break.RowNo, 2) = Break.RowNo
'                aTab(Break.RowNo, 3) = Break.AssetCUR
'                aTab(Break.RowNo, 4) = Break.AcctCUR
'                aTab(Break.RowNo, 5) = Break.PriceDiff
'                aTab(Break.RowNo, 6) = Break.MsgStr
                'xrow = 1
                xrow = xrow + 1
'                aTab(xrow, 1) = "SMALL BREAKS"
'                aTab(xrow, 2) = Break.RowNo
'                aTab(xrow, 3) = Break.AssetCUR
'                aTab(xrow, 4) = Break.AcctCUR
'                aTab(xrow, 5) = Break.PriceDiff
'                aTab(xrow, 6) = Break.MsgStr
                '''Debug.Print Break.EntityID

            End If


        Next



End Sub
```

**Here is my BeakInfo Class Module: I am still learning with Objects and Classes but as you may see above I am really stuggling trying to wrap my head of evaluating EACH ROW which is a single BREAK OBJECT with multile evaluations while storing the USER INPUT CRITERIA, i.e. multiple OR values while rotating between MULTIPLE AND Values.**

- The Macro needs to be implemented in a flexible way where the User
  could specify and Criteria under any Field Column Header with any
  Value using a list of Operators and Fields.
- I have listed all possible user criteria on a separate sheet as I
  aimed to standardize all the Possible Operators, Logic, and Criteria
  a User may input.
- The first code snippet in this Post represents my core code and as you may see I Struggle evaluating and storing multiple user criteria.
  I was thinking maybe I should move towards class procedures such as
  Getters, Setters, Let Class Method?

  Option Explicit

  ```
      Public AcctCUR As String
      Public AssetCUR As String

      Public PriceDiff As Currency
      Public PriceDiff2 As Currency
      Public PriceDiff3 As Currency
      Public PriceDiff4 As Currency
      Public PriceDiff5 As Currency


      Public MsgStr As Double

      Public RowNo As Integer
  ```

Here is a Sheet I named `BackEnd` My way of standardizing all potential User Input:

> ```
>     Field Logic   Break
> AcctCUR   <   CASH
> AssetCUR  <>  CASH COLLATERAL
> AssetID   =   Cash Collateral
> Coupon    >   Dividends
> EntityID      Futures
> EntityName        GNMA or FNMA
> InvType       Loans
> IssueDes      NON BASE SMALL BREAKS
> IssueName     Other
> LedgAcctDes       Receivable Or Payable
> LedgerAMT     REPO
> LngSht        SMALL BREAKS
> MatDate       SWAPS
> MsgStr        TIPS_TREASURY
> NetAMTL       URGL
> PAID      URGL TIPS
> PAIDType      
> PriceDiff     
> PST       
> RowNo     
> RuleID        
> Sector        
> SecurityType      
> ShareClass        
> SrcDes        
> SubSecType        
> UpDate        
> ValDate
> ```

Comment: Tbh I think you're expecting a lot of people to read all that and work out exactly what you are asking. I suggest breaking it down into simpler digestible elements with a specific question, spread over several questions if necessary.

Comment: Yes I feared that. Perhaps just what is in bold.

Comment: So, Break Objects are data filters ?